# Performing Nonauthoritative restore of AD on offline DC

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, directory-services

I have a domain controller that's been offline for 3 months. If I bring it back online normally, it will cause issues due to the tombstone life now being over the 60 day expiry. What's the best method for bringing this DC back online? Would performing a Nonauthoritative Restore of AD be easiest? So:

1. Boot the DC up off the network
2. Press F8 to start the domain controller in DSRM
3. Connect to the network
4. Select the option for DSRM at recovery menu Once
5. Nonauthoritative Restore is complete, reboot

Or should I just go into safemode, demote the DC back to member server, run a metadata cleanup on the domain, then re-promote the server back to a DC?

Comment: Are you sure TSL is 60?  New installations have this set to 180 since 2003.  What is the output of the following command: dsquery * "cn=directory service,cn=windows nt,cn=services,cn=configuration,dc=[domain],dc=com" -scope base -attr tombstonelifetime

Comment: When I run that it just returns 'tombstonelifetime' no value. If I run ADSI Edit and browse to that location, 'TombStoneLifeTime' shows <Not Set>.

Comment: I think if it is 'Not Set' then it defaults to 60 days, even if the domain is Windows 2003 R2 Sp2

Answer (score 1):

DSRM, dcpromo /forceremoval, and metadata cleanup.

Microsoft recommends that tombstone lifetime be set to 180 days, you may want to consider that, as it also affects the lifetime of your backups and ability to recover.